# I can't show my checkbox results

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPGWv.png)
 I'm trying to make Club activity Registration Page. First I choose club, then page shows the list of involved students in checkbox. After I choose students and submit, I tried to show all student's list and their 'atclub'.

But It only shows 'go to the home'. What's wrong with meㅠㅠㅠㅠ??? Please help me..

When I checked nothing and submit, I tried to show error message but it doesn't work. it makes error instead. How can I solve it? Please help me..!!

in views.py

```
def register(request, club_id):
    club = get_object_or_404(Club, pk=club_id)
    try:
        students = request.POST.getlist('students[]')
    except(KeyError, Student.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'club/detail.html', {
            'club':club,
            'error_message':"You didn't choose any students.."
        })


    else:
        for studentid in students:
            studentss = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=studentid)
            studentss.atclub = club
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('club:results'), )

def results(request):
    a={'Name':'Club'}

    for students in Student.objects.all():
        a.update({students.student:students.atclub})
    return render(request, 'club/results.html', a)
```

in results.html -- this shows just 'Go to the Home'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {% for student in a %}
        <li>{{student.key}}--{{student.value}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'club:index'%}">Go to the Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

in detail.html -- for choosing students by using checkbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> {{club.club}}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'club:register' club.id %}" method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {%for student in club.student_set.all%}
    <input type="checkbox" name="students[]" id="student{{ forloop.counter }}"  value="{{ student.id }}"/>
    <label for="student{{ forloop.counter }}">{{student.student}}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in models.py -- class Student

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clubs = models.ManyToManyField(Club)
    class_s = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isfilled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    atclub = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student

    def atclub(self):
        return self.atclub
```

---

in whole views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.views import View, generic
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import *

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse(home.html)
#home.html 연결 및 수정

class IndexView(generic. ListView):
    template_name='club/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'club_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Club.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Club
    template_name='club/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Club.objects.all()

def register(request, club_id):
    club = get_object_or_404(Club, pk=club_id)
    try:
        students = request.POST.getlist('students[]')
    except(KeyError, Student.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'club/detail.html', {
            'club':club,
            'error_message':"학생을 선택하지 않았습니다."
        })
    #에러 처리가 잘 안된다. 왜지...웨지...걈자...(현타)(말잇못
    #학생 선택 안하면 ValueError

    else:
        for studentid in students:
            studentss = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=studentid)
            #QuerySet으로 가져온다 -> 객체 소환 X
            studentss.atclub = club
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('club:results'), )

def results(request):
    a={'Name':'Club'}

    for students in Student.objects.all():
        a.update({students.student:students.atclub})
    return render(request, 'club/results.html', a)
```

Comment: You've posted this question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770920/how-can-i-get-values-in-html-checkbox, did you know you can edit the OP

Comment: Oh I just didn't notice about that.

Comment: OP = Original Post sometimes

Comment: can you give me a hint or solution?

Comment: can you edit your question by adding how the `register` view really looks like, the whole code

Comment: I just added the whole views.py. and image the register view looks like. (I'm bad at English so if i misunderstood your question then sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your view to the following way:

```
def register(request, club_id):
    club = get_object_or_404(Club, pk=club_id)
    error_message = None
    if request.method == 'POST': # When user submit form
         students = request.POST.getlist('students[]')
         if students:
             for studentid in students:
                 studentss = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=studentid)
                 #QuerySet으로 가져온다 -> 객체 소환 X
                 studentss.atclub = club
                 studentss.save()
                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('club:results'))
         else:
             error_message = "You didn't choose any students.."
             # error_message = '학생을 선택하지 않았습니다.'
    context = {'club':club,'error_message':error_message,}
    return render(request, 'club/detail.html', context)
```

And in your result view, you don't really need to iterate the queryset:

```
def results(request):
    a = Student.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'club/results.html', {'a':a})
```

And finally, in your template, the `a` would be easy to loop through:

```
{% for student in a %}
    <li>{{student.student}}--{{student.atclub}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but I yet have errors in 'def results', How can I change this part?

Comment: def results(request, context):
    return render(request, 'club/results.html', context) ____________I changed results in this way and error message 'results() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context''

Comment: Thank you for your kindness..!! But I still have small problems that it printed on the page '1101 나연(student name)--<bound method Student.atclub of <Student: 1101 (student name)>>', Not a name of club..

Comment: You still miss something in my answer, can you update your question with how your code looks like now. Just add it below your question with a title **UPDATE**

Comment: get it, remove this in your model `def atclub(self):
        return self.atclub`

Comment: I'm sorry for late! I just fixing something else in my codes. Thank you for your help really much!!  May I ask you something else...? If I want to reset it then how can I do?

Comment: Just the list of [student--atclub]. It sometimes doesn't update though I registered one student in other club..

Comment: Sorry! What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I made an 'isfilled'(boolean) to avoid some student registered in more than one club. if one student already registered, then Is there any solution to block registering?

Comment: just with a `if else` statement, `if not student.atclub:` then proceed

Comment: some problems happen.. only the last value registered.

Comment: I suggest using `atclub` as a `ForeignKey` instead of `CharField`